# Trying to insert sort a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to Insert Sort random integers into the linked list from smallest to largest. Every time I run this method it will begin sorting and printing but will eventually give me a nullpointerexception? Any help is appreciated.

```
public void insertInOrder(int x) {
    if (head == null) {

        head = new Node(x);

    } else {
        Node prev;
        Node curr;

        for (prev = null, curr = head;
            (curr != null) && (x > curr.getNumber()); 
            prev = curr, curr = curr.getNext()) {}

        if (prev == null) {
            insertAtHead(x);
        }

        if (curr == null) {
            insertAtTail(x);
        } else {
            Node nNex = new Node(x);
            nNex.setNext(curr);
            prev.setNext(nNex); // NullPointerException is raised here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the NullPointerException occur?

Comment: at prev.setNext(nNex);

Comment: After the check `prev == null` the `prev` variable will not get updated/changed anymore. So it seems unevitable that at `prev.setNext()` the NullPointerException is raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do an if, else if, and else statement instead of a double if and else:

This is what you have

```
if (prev == null) {
    insertAtHead(x);
}

if (curr == null) {
    insertAtTail(x);
} else {
    Node nNex = new Node(x);
    nNex.setNext(curr);
    prev.setNext(nNex);
}
```

You check if prev is null, If it is it goes in the first if statement, but if curr is null, when you enter the else statement prev is still null. You should do:

```
if (prev == null) {
    insertAtHead(x);
}

else if (curr == null) {
    insertAtTail(x);
} else {
    Node nNex = new Node(x);
    nNex.setNext(curr);
    prev.setNext(nNex);
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Mark the answer as the correct answer to your problem